# How to decode the instruction data of a transaction retrieved via getTransaction

Tags: transactions, decode

Hey I wanted to build a parser, for spl transactions to figure out the kind of instruction via instruction data(first byte)/u8/first index of the byte array( tells me if its burn,transfer,etc.
but the instruction data returned seems to be encoded ? wanted to know which library base58 decode is compatible for decoding it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the typescript IDL available you can decode it with the `BorshCoder` as part of the `@project-serum/anchor` package. For instance to parse the first instruction of a transaction you can use below example.

```
const coder = new BorshCoder(IDL);
const tx = await connection.getTransaction(signature);
const ix = coder.instruction.decode(tx.transaction.message.instructions[0].data, "base58");
```

Comment: wanted to know how to do it manually incase the idl is not present, i decoded using base 58 and got a buffer with some values how to convert that to a uint8 array or in rust terms a [u8] so i can take the first index value and determine what kind of instruction was it manually.

Comment: Use `deserializeUnchecked` from `borsh`. if you google on that you will find some examples, for instance https://docs.bonfida.org/collection/v/fan-ti-zhong-wen/tokens

Comment: What actually goes in the IDL argument in the first line of this response?

Comment: @m2sa the IDL is the Interface Description Language, which can be derived from the program. If you build a program with anchor, the IDL is generated automatically in the build tree or you can also derive it from chain with anchors `fetchIdl` command. If you build a "vanilla" program its a bit more difficult.

Comment: hmm....so i'm importing at the time like so: `import * as anchor from @project-serum/anchor`, but then when i try anchor.fetchIdl, it tells me that this is not a function. am i importing it from the wrong place?

Comment: follow up note: i discovered `anchor.Program.fetchIdl`, but when i try to put the programId that i'm after, i get the following error: ```node:internal/fs/utils:671
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(propName, ['string', 'Buffer', 'URL'], path);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined```

Comment: @Omega one other question - in some cases, it seems that there is data within the args once the instruction data is decoded. This arg data appears to also be encoded. Are there standard methods for decoding this type of data once the instruction is decoded? (example txn: https://solana.fm/tx/3E4fgXr9y3fjKpNWcoNW7HtMeZnYc7Zuz1bLhpMi2QVELiB7giLFWCFTZRQ2pfVNphstCNUtTyVAMSzZRwqtSt6T)

Comment: You can use the same IDL to process instruction arguments. Honestly, these are all detailed questions on their own, please create a new question on solana.stackexchange.com